# How to fuzzy lookup a string in one column to another column ignoring sub-setted words

Tags: r, stringr

I have the following 2 dataframes `vendor_list` and `firm_list`:

```
MARKET_ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
MARKET_NAME <- c("DELHI","MUMBAI","BANGALORE","KOLKATA","CHENNAI")
vendor_list <- data.frame(MARKET_ID,MARKET_NAME)
```

```
MARKET_NAME <- c("DELHI MUNICIPAL CORP","DELHI","MUMBAI","BENGALURU","BANGALORES","CITYKOLKATA")
POPULATION <- c(1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000)
firm_list <- data.frame(MARKET_NAME,POPULATION)
```

I need to search for strings in MARKET_NAME column in `vendor_list` dataframe in MARKET_NAME column in `firm_list` dataframe. But there are certain conditions:

It should only show as a match if the string is present as a stand alone block, i.e. it should not be a sub-set of the word.

So,

1. The match of DELHI to DELHI MUNICIPAL CORP is `TRUE`
2. The match of DELHI to DELHI is `TRUE`
3. The match of BANGALORE to BANGALORES is `FALSE` as BANGALORE is a sub-set of BANGALORES
4. The match of KOLKATA to CITYKOLKATA is `FALSE` as KOLKATA is a sub-set of CITYKOLKATA

Thus, the final dataframe `final_market_info` after lookup should look like this:

```
| MARKET_ID| MARKET_NAME.x |  MARKET_NAME.y      | POPULATION |
|    1     |     DELHI     | DELHI MUNICIPAL CORP| 1000       |
|    1     |     DELHI     |   DELHI             | 2000       |
|    2     |     MUMBAI    |   MUMBAI            | 3000       |
```

I had tried stringdist_join in stringr package using lcs and jw method but it was not giving me correct result like this.

Comment: `Market_name` in `vendor_list` only has 4 elements (should have 5)

Comment: Have you noticed the solution I posted? Does it help?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Thank you so much. I was looking exactly for this!

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Hey I think you did it the other way round. If you look at the desirable dataframe, it is different. I tried doing it by interchanging vendor_list with firm_list to get the result but its showing error.

Comment: Not sure I understand: `match` is the equivalent of your column `MARKET_NAME.x`, right? If so, just rename it using `rename()`. Anyway your desired output and mine contain identical data. So the solution should be alright (and you might consider accepting it)

Comment: Actually, your solution was 100% right. the vendor_list$MARKET_NAME column had multiple NA's, and thus the result I was getting was erraneous. I just substituted the NA's & got accurate result. Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
firm_list %>%
  mutate(match = str_extract(MARKET_NAME, str_c("\\b", vendor_list$MARKET_NAME, collapse = "|", "\\b"))) %>%
  left_join(., vendor_list %>% rename(match = MARKET_NAME), by = "match")
           MARKET_NAME POPULATION  match MARKET_ID
1 DELHI MUNICIPAL CORP       1000  DELHI         1
2                DELHI       2000  DELHI         1
3               MUMBAI       3000 MUMBAI         2
4            BENGALURU       4000   <NA>        NA
5           BANGALORES       5000   <NA>        NA
6          CITYKOLKATA       6000   <NA>        NA
```

The point here is that the elements in `vendor_list$MARKET_NAME` are wrapped into word `\\b`oundary markers to get exact matches and concatenated as an alternation pattern.

To remove the rows without matches, use `inner_join` instead of `left_join`:

```
firm_list %>%
   mutate(match = str_extract(MARKET_NAME, str_c("\\b", vendor_list$MARKET_NAME, collapse = "|", "\\b"))) %>%
   inner_join(., vendor_list %>% rename(match = MARKET_NAME), by = "match")
           MARKET_NAME POPULATION  match MARKET_ID
1 DELHI MUNICIPAL CORP       1000  DELHI         1
2                DELHI       2000  DELHI         1
3               MUMBAI       3000 MUMBAI         2
```